# About Matrix multiplication in R: requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Tags: r, matrix

```
Error in Ws %*% as.matrix(endog) : 
requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

where ‘Ws’ is a N*N spatial weight matrix and ‘endog’is N*3 (we have three endogenous variables)
I cannot understand why this error occours because when I set only one endogenous variable my code works well.
What's more, three endogenous variables are not dummy.
Is it because that two of these endogenous variables are interaction? Or because of the package 'splm/spgm' cannot allow for extra endogenous variables?

Here is part of my code:

```
c11_omega <- interaction(mydata$c11,mydata$omega)
d11_omega <- interaction(mydata$d11,mydata$omega)
endog = ~ omega + c11_omega + d11_omega
instruments = ~ XI + c11_XI + d11_XI
```

and the regression is:

```
fm <- ex ~ c11 + d11 + control variables
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think you can coerce a formula-class object (endog) to matrix. Can you?

Comment: Please take the time to make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).